# Gammu Timeout on identifying modem

Tags: gammu

I setup gammu on OSX and has a configuration as below:

```
[gammu]

port =  /dev/tty.usbmodem24127
model  = 
connection  = at115200
synchronizetime  = yes
logfile  = 
logformat  = nothing
use_locking = 
gammuloc  =
```

I got this error "No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected." when I do gammu identify.

However if I restart my modem and do gammu identify immediately, gammu identified the modem without any problem. But then if I try to do gammu identify again it won't work.

Any idea what is going on? Can I increase the time out?

***Update :**
Not only gamma can't establish a connection but even using a screen command like "screen /dev/tty.usbmodem24127" won't work.

The port is always busy even nothing is connected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please include debug log as well? Check http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/ for information how to obtain it.

Comment: Just update my post...apparently the reason is not on gammu.